# Compute a complex power

Tags: code-golf, math, complex-numbers

## The Rundown

Given any input **x** and **y**, perform a complex operation, and print a corresponding result.

## How your program should work

1. Given an input **x** and **y** in the form **z = x+yi**, find **z<sup>i-z</sup>**
2. If the absolute real value of **z<sup>i-z</sup>** is larger than the absolute imaginary part, print the real part; vice versa for the other way around. If both values are equal, print one of the values.

## Example

```
x: 2
y: 0
```

Therefore:

```
z = 2
z^(i-z) ~= 0.192309 + 0.159740i
```

Since the real part has a larger absolute value than the imaginary part, the program returns

```
0.192309
```

#### More examples

```
z = 1+i >> 0.5
z = i >> 1
z = 0.5 >> 1.08787
z = -2+8i >> 2.22964E7
z = -10i >> 3.13112E7
```

Comment: Pro-tip: get rid of the bonus!

Comment: [Things to avoid when writing challenges - bonuses in code-golf](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8106/34718)

Comment: It would be nice if you gave more input-output pairs.

Comment: @user1502040 Sure thing

Comment: Raising a complex numbers to a complex power is discontinuous and depends on the branch cut used. Can you specify that? Though I guess everyone will just be using built-in math operations and those probably all use the same convention.

Comment: Do we have to take `X` and `Y` as separate inputs? Some languages can take complex numbers as inputs.

Comment: @ScottMilner, No you can take z as an entire input.

Comment: Does "larger" mean to pick the value with greatest absolute value, rather than (what most have assumed) to pick the maximal value? A test case of `-2+i` could be used for that (`z^(i-z)=3-4i` so `3>-4` vs `abs(-4)>abs(3)`).

Comment: Will the real and imaginary parts of the input always be integers? Your test cases seem to suggest that.

Comment: what is the problem? why [on hold]? larger means larger and not abosolute larger... possible there is to clear if z=a+i*b with a and b in R or integers, but it is better in the set R

Comment: The "absolute value" clarification/change has invalidated most of the answers.

Comment: @YamB: https://github.com/DaveJarvis/sequential -- cheers from Victoria.

Answer (score 7):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>8</s> 11 bytes

Thanks Johnathan Allan for updating the answer with the rules change.

```
ı_*@µĊ,ḞAÞṪ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#ASUA2v//xLFfKkDCtcSKLOG4nkHDnuG5qv///y0yKzFq9W5vLWNhY2hl)

```
ı_*@        z^(i-z)
    µ       new monadic link
     Ċ,Ḟ    pair real and imaginary parts
        AÞṪ sort by absolute value and take last value
```

Comment: Make it `ı_*@µĊ,ḞAÞṪ` and you may well have the only valid entry (given the change to require the maximal value in absolute terms, such that, for example, `-2+1j` returns `-4.0` rather than `3.0`).

Answer (score 6):

## Python 2, 45 bytes

```python
def f(z):z=z**(1j-z);print max(z.real,z.imag)
```

[**Try it online**](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#HchBDsIgEADAO6/guFssYZuYGIyPIboopG0Iwdju56l6mcP0B0cdQdDLTYYBKI@C11LT2vQSNhBbOcwnsWkJT@yt7l7pzyvNrMlHSGt5N0BUvN25NO/6ZFxWZCgr98eefzFO5vKVXD4A) - *all test cases*

Programming languages often use `j` instead of `i`. That is the case in Python. See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24812444/2415524) for more information on why.

Answer (score 5):

### Mathematica, <strike>21</strike> 22 bytes

*Edit: Thanks to JungHwan Min for saving 3 btyes*

```
Max@ReIm[#^(I-#)]&
```

Pure function which expects a complex number as an argument. If an exact number is passed, then an exact number will be returned (e.g. `1/2` gives `Sqrt[2] Cos[Log[2]]`). The problem spec was edited after I posted my solution to specify that the absolute value should be used. The best I can come up with for that is `MaximalBy[ReIm[#^(I-#)],Abs][[1]]&` or `Last@MaximalBy[Abs]@ReIm[#^(I-#)]&`, both `34` bytes.

Comment: `Max` does not need to be the head. It returns the max value no matter how deep the input `List` is (e.g. `Max[1, {2, {3}}]` returns `3`). Also, the question only specifies that you print the values, so I don't think you would need `N`: `Max@ReIm[#^(I-#)]&` would work.

Answer (score 3):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 10 bytes

```
Jy-^&ZjhX>
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/matl#@@9VqRunFpWVEWH3/7@ukbZFJgA) Or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/nexus/matl#S/jvVakbpxaVlRFh998l5L@hdiZXJpchl66RtkUml66hQSYA).

#### Explanation

Consider input `-2+8i` as an example.

```
J     % Push i (imaginary unit)
      % STACK: i
y     % Implicit input. Duplicate from below
      % STACK: -2+8i, i, -2+8i
-     % Subtract
      % STACK: -2+8i, 2-7i
^     % Power
      % STACK: 3168271.58+22296434.47i
&Zj   % Real and imaginary parts
      % STACK: 3168271.58, 22296434.47
h     % Concatenate
      % STACK: [3168271.58 22296434.47]
X>    % Maximum. Implicitly display
      % STACK: 22296434.47
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), 29 bytes

```matlab
@(z)max(real(z^(i-z)./[1 i]))
```

This defines an anonymous function. It works in MATLAB too.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/octave#@@@gUaWZm1ihUZSamKNRFaeRqVulqacfbaiQGaup@T9NwVYhMa/YmitNw1A7U1NHIU0DQhqCSV0jbQsIX9fQIFPzPwA)

#### Explanation

Element-wise dividing (`./`) the number `z^(i-z)` by the array `[1 i]` and taking the real part gives an array with the real and imaginary parts of `z^(i-z)`.

Answer (score 2):

## TI-BASIC, <s>40</s>, <s>32</s>, <s>31</s> 29 bytes

*Saved a byte thanks to [@Conor O'Brien](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/31957/conor-obrien)*

```
Z^(i-Z→A                   #Perform operation, store as A, 8 bytes
:real(A)>imag(A            #Test if real part is greater than imaginary, 9 bytes
:Ansreal(A)+imag(Anot(Ans  #Determine output and print, 12 bytes
```

Takes input as a complex number on the `Z` variable.

TI-BASIC uses its own encoding, you can find it [here](http://tibasicdev.wikidot.com/tokens).

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth, 16 Bytes

```
=b^Q-Q.j;eS,ebsb
```

Answer (score 1):

## C (GCC), <s>93</s> 79 + 4 (`-lm`) = <s>97</s> 83 bytes

*Saved 14 bytes thanks to @ceilingcat!*

```c
float f(_Complex z){z=cpow(z,csqrt(-1)-z);return cimag(z)>creal(z)?cimag(z):z;}
```

Including the header `complex.h` is longer than that ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/c-gcc#bY7NCsIwEITvPkUoCBvbSFMQxKIefA0hhJCUQH5qGrGk@OrWWvDUHmZ2@GYPMyrjeUQK2M3b1sgeJTyks2j9C1IhukeIQCgmCddBxmdwSGjLG0j4IoLkZgrXPzml@j1arh3goQ3aRQXZVt3dUlmxUVDhn9OcMdlH6TrtHWOI6hmvwnJ/mC@p8uNu9YPQclls8LTrI5ThTTcSY78)

Comment: Why +4 bytes? I count 3,  `-`, `l`, and `m`.

Comment: @Riker normal compiling is `gcc file.c -o exe`, so this flag adds 4 bytes: space, `-`, `l`, and `m`. (At least that's how I see it counted when compiling.)

Comment: @ceilingcat oh didn't know that was possible. Thanks!

Comment: [54 bytes](https://tio.run/##ZYxBCsIwFET3PUUoCD80UVMQCuLKawgSQn/5kKQhRiwpXt1IzdLFzHvMYoycjCkF7awTQ7hfZxfsuLDM1zimZ/QMnV4gHxSJfDFhfkEWimTm/PwuTpMHvoZIPiG0O7z5/7SiQej51qpTVKVif/pB9t1QB6mOxJvt@mPQ6ulRpHVf "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>25</s> 35 bytes

**EDIT**: Fixed to comply with new absolute value rule.

```ruby
->z{(z**(1i-z)).rect.max_by(&:abs)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/ruby#@69rV1WtUaWlpWGYqVulqalXlJpcopebWBGfVKmhZpWYVKxZ@/8/AA)

This creates an anonymous function.

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org/), 24 bytes

```
{($_**(i-$_)).reals.max}
```

`$_` is the possibly complex argument; `$_ ** (i - $_)` is the expression to be computed; `.reals` is a `Complex` method that returns a list of the real and imaginary parts; and finally `.max` returns the larger of the two.

Answer (score 1):

## TI-Basic, <s>19</s> 16 bytes

```
Ans^(i-Ans
max(real(Ans),imag(Ans
```

`real(` and `imag(` are two-byte tokens.

Run with `5+3i:prgmNAME` (`5+3i` being the argmuent, `NAME` being the program name.)

Answer (score 1):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 18 bytes

18 bytes (https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS/)
28 bytes (UTF-8)

⍵ is a complex number ajb = a+bi

```apl
{⌈/9 11∘.○⍵*0j1-⍵}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///v/pRT4e@pYKh4aOOGXqPpnc/6t2qZZBlqAuka///BwA)

Answer (score 0):

### R, 38 bytes

```
pryr::f({z=z^(1i-z);max(Re(z),Im(z))})
```

Anonymous function. Takes a (possibly) complex number `z`, takes it to the specified power, and then returns the `max` of the `Re`al and `Im`aginary parts.

Answer (score 0):

## Axiom, 60 bytes

```
f(z:Complex Float):Float==(y:=z^(%i-z);max(real(y),imag(y)))
```

test code and results; i follow as the other the precedent version of the question...

```
(28) -> [[k,f(k)] for k in [1+%i,%i,1,-2+8*%i,-10*%i]]
   (28)
   [[1.0 + %i,0.5], [%i,1.0], [1.0,1.0],
    [- 2.0 + 8.0 %i,22296434.4737098688 53],
    [- 10.0 %i,31311245.9804955291 66]]
```

Answer (score 0):

## C# - 189 Bytes

```
double f(double x, double y){double r,t,m,c;r=Math.Sqrt(x*x+y*y);t=Math.Atan2(y,x);m=Math.Pow(r,-x)*Math.Exp(y*t-t);c=Math.Cos((1-y)*Math.Log(r)-t*x);return m*(2*c*c<1?Math.Sqrt(1-c*c):c);}
```

Readable:

```
double f(double x, double y){
double r, t, m, c;
r = Math.Sqrt(x * x + y * y);
t = Math.Atan2(y, x);
m = Math.Pow(r, -x) * Math.Exp(y * t - t);
c = Math.Cos((1 - y) * Math.Log(r) - t * x);
return m * (2 * c * c < 1 ? Math.Sqrt(1 - c * c) : c); }
```

Explanation: Decided not to use any Complex libraries.

$$
\begin{align}
z & = x + iy \\
& = r e^{it} \\
z^{i-z} & = (re^{it})^{(-x +i(1-y))} \\
& = r^{-x} r^{i(1-y)} e^{-xit} e^{t(y-1)} \\
& = r^{-x} e^{t(y-1)} e^{i((1-y)\ln(r)-xt)} \text{ (as }r^i = e^{i\ln(r)}\text{)}
\end{align}
$$

Let this be equal to \$me^{ia}\$ where

$$m = r^{-x} e^{t(y-1)}$$
$$a = (1-y)\ln(r)-xt$$

Then \$\Re(z^{i-z})=m \cos a\$ and \$\Im(z^{i-z})=m \sin a\$

The maximum absolute value can be determined by the \$\cos a\$ and \$\sin a\$ terms, with these being equal at \$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\$ (hence the test \$2c^2 < 1\$).

As mentioned, raising to a complex exponent is dependent on choosing a particular branch cut ( e.g. \$z = 1\$ could be \$e^{i\pi}\$ or \$e^{3i\pi}\$ - raising this to \$i\$ gives a real part of \$e^{-\pi}\$ or \$e^{-3\pi}\$ respectively), however, I have just used the convention of \$t \in [0,2\pi)\$ as per the question.